# Multiple statements of "for" loop without block

Tags: c, for-loop

Following code snippet was given to me in an interview and asked me, is it possible to evaluate all the statements of for loop without block?

```
int i, n, t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm;

for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", t1);
    nextTerm = t1 + t2;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = nextTerm;
}
```

I asked him, I think not possible to evaluate multiple statements of for loop without block. But, my friend told me, It is possible using **comma** operator, like this :

```
int i, n, t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm;

for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d ", t1),
    nextTerm = t1 + t2,
    t1 = t2,
    t2 = nextTerm;
```

I know `comma` operator how to work for single line statement. But i wondering how to work `comma` operator for multiple line?

Also, Is there any other way to do this task?

Comment: That's a single line for your compiler.

Comment: I hope the interview went bad because, trust me, you don't want that job. If they couldn't come up with better interview questions, then it suggests they are a bunch of amateurs.

Comment: In most contexts, C treats a line break no differently from any other white space character (such as a space).  Exceptions would be inside quoted strings, preprocessor directives, etc.

Comment: It's odd that the candidate didn't say "replace the loop body with a function call".

Comment: The real answer would be "While it is possible in C, No, this cannot be done in a way that wouldn't be slammed right in my face by any sane reviewer"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note, **don't ever** write code like the above or like I am about to do!

You have an answer about multiple lines, but the other question about another way to write this is:

```
for(int i= 0; i < 10; nextTerm = t1 + t2,
                      t1 = t2,
                      t2 = nextTerm,
                      i++)
    printf("%d ", t1);
```

Or even, taken to the extreme...

```
for(int i= 0; i < 10; printf("%d ", t1),
                      nextTerm = t1 + t2,
                      t1 = t2,
                      t2 = nextTerm,
                      i++)
    /* Hey, empty loop! */;
```

Comment: I actually quite that style since it tells you there is nothing funky going on in the loop body (`break`, `continue`, &c.)

Comment: Why not use this instead? `#define FOO(x) for(in??=??=x i=0;!prin??=??=x??=??=f("%d ",x??=??=1,nex??=??=x??=??=Term=x??=??=1+x??=??=2)|i<10;x??=??=1=x??=??=2,x??=??=2=nex??=??=x??=??=Term,i++)??<??>`. Call as `FOO(t);`. Output: `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89` (Fibonacci sequence)

Answer (score 5):

This *is* a single line statement, formatted over several lines.

It is complete nonsense to use the comma operator like this. Removing the block fills no purpose what so ever - it just makes your code more dangerous and harder to read, for absolutely nothing gained. Use semicolons.

*Always* use a compound statement after a loop. *Even* if there is just one single statement inside the loop - one of the most expensive bugs in history, "the Apple gotofail" was caused by lax use of braces.

Comment: Might be worth adding a link to an explanation of this "Apple gotofail" -> https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/  / or post the code of it and explain it in your answer

Comment: @Rafalon Nah it was just an anecdote, it is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how many lines there are. What matters is whether or not there is single statement. And statements are delimited by a semi-colon (`;`).

Lexically, C code ignores white-spaces that aren't needed to separate tokens. So this multi-line statement:

```
printf("%d ", t1),
nextTerm = t1 + t2,
t1 = t2,
t2 = nextTerm;
```

Is the same as though it was written in a single line:

```
printf("%d ", t1), nextTerm = t1 + t2, t1 = t2, t2 = nextTerm;
```

But while this may feel clever, don't write code like this. It's an exercise in obfuscation.

Comment: @Jayesh - NO! I wrote as much at the end.